# How to find out if the pc is connected to a network?

Tags: ruby, networking

Hi
following problem:
I want to write a small script on my notebook, which checks if a given host is online, but I'm not always connected to a network. So I want the script to do nothing if I'm not connected.
How can I find out, whether I'm connected or not?
My current solution is pinging google, but I'm not really happy with this.

Thank you for any suggestions
Baju

P.S.: Should have mentioned: I'm running Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: I think you should define "being online" better. Is your computer online if it sees your local home network? Is it online if it reaches your provider, but not other sites?

Comment: It's online when the modem stops making the screeching noise and the lights are blinking. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command to check if networking is configured properly differs based on Unix or Windows.  If your host machine uses DHCP to get it's IP address and gateway information you can use the `ipconfig` (windows) or `ifconfig` (Unix) to query information about the network.  Granted you'll have to parse their output.

*edit: changed Unix command based on the code sample linked in the comment*

Comment: Thank you! I hacked this: https://gist.github.com/726980 . Okay, it's a bit Q&D. Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks reasonable to me.  If you carefully crafted your Regex, you would be able to do the match on the entire string instead of iterating over the lines.  However, sometimes that is more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: once you get the gateway you can try to ping it to make sure you are actually on the network.  That should help you discover situations where you computer has IP settings, but is disconnected from the network.